# Thread only run 1

Tags: python, multithreading

this code is print out random number is prim but when I run some time it only run t1 ,some time t2 and don't have any problem report . Can you tell me the reason and help me to fix it

```
from random import seed
from random import randint
import threading as Thread
def prim(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            count += 1
    if count == 2:
        return True
    return False
def p():
    for _ in range(20):
            value = randint(1, 100)
    for _ in range(20):
        if prim(value) :
            print(Thread.current_thread().getName(),value)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    t1= Thread.Thread(name="t1: ",target=p)
    t2= Thread.Thread(name="t2: ",target=p)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Comment: ```for _ in range(20): value = randint(1, 100)``` why have you done this? ```value``` will take only one value

Comment: i don't know im learning . how to fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this program?

Comment: random 20 number is prim and print out with 2 thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both threads a running, but each thread only checks one number. Use a list to create multiple values.

```
def p():
    lst = []
    for _ in range(20):
            lst.append(randint(1, 100))
    for value in lst:
        if prim(value) :
            print(Thread.current_thread().getName(),value)
```